# use variable in terragrunt config

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt, terraform-aws-modules

can we use terraform variables inside terragrunt config?

below is my terragrunt config.

```
#terragrunt.hcl

remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = {
    path      = "remote_state.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  # Terragrunt built-in function:
  # sets key relative to the modules
  config = {
    bucket         = ${var.bucket_name}
    key            = ${var.key}
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

Inside root.yaml file, I have passed input values for variable bucket_name and key. these variables are defined inside terraform modules.

```
#root.yaml
bucket_name: "s3-bucket"
key:    "foo"
```

this is not working, terragrunt is complaining that the variable is not defined. without creating a new variable to use for terragrunt, can't we use terraform variable inside terragrunt config?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare terraform vars using env:

```
export TF_VAR_bucket_name=mybucket
```

And terragrunt config:

```
config = {
  bucket = get_env("TF_VAR_bucket_name", "otherbucket")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terragrunt doesn't have variables on hcl level, but it allows you to use locals that can be read from files:

```
#terragrunt.hcl
locals {
  config_vars    = read_terragrunt_config("config.hcl")
}

remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = {
    path      = "remote_state.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  # Terragrunt built-in function:
  # sets key relative to the modules
  config = {
    bucket         = "${local.config_vars.locals.bucket_name}"
    key            = "${local.config_vars.locals.key}"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}
```

```
# config.hcl:
locals {
    bucket_name = "s3-bucket"
    key         = "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using yaml as a source for your configs, you can decode it in locals

```
locals {
 vars        = yamldecode(file(("root.yaml"))
 bucket_name = local.vars.bucket_name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually played around with this for a few hours and realized a few things.

**Approach 1: Read variables from OS environment**

if you are going to read the file as a system-level environment variable (a variable you defined in, let's say, Debian or RedHat Linux), the documentation suggests this:

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#get_env

> Note that Terraform will read environment variables that start with
> the prefix TF_VAR_, so one way to share a variable named foo between
> Terraform and Terragrunt is to set its value as the environment
> variable TF_VAR_foo and to read that value in using this get_env()
> built-in function.

That implies that you can set `TF_VAR_foo` at the OS level and it will be available to `get_env()` function. I opened up ~/.bash_profile and added `export TF_VAR_env=sandbox` and ran `source ~/.bash_profile` but it didn't work. I then tried `export env=sandbox` in ~/.bash_profile and that indeed worked with `get_env("env", "")`.

**Approach 2: Read variables from file**

Terragrunt has a `file()` built-in function. You can use it to read variables stored in a yml file:

```
locals {
  settings_default    = yamldecode(file("defaults.yml"))
}
```

Inside defaults.yml, you can have key/value pairs:

```
---
some_var: some_val
```